# Can't add reference to COM dll to WP8 project

Tags: com, windows-phone-8

I've created WP8 C# project, added few native projects to solution - COM dlls, and now I want to add references to those dlls in C# project, in order to use them, but can't do that - getting

```
A reference to higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project
```

How this can be fixed? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly add COM libraries to a Windows Phone 8 project. You'll have to use a WinRT wrapper, or better, rewrite the entire COM part in WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference just any assembly - native assemblies must be built as Windows Phone Runtime components. If you have access to source codes, you can try to rebuild them as Windows Phone Runtime components, otherwise you're probably out of luck.